# jquery how to get array value from a variable with in the array index brackets

Tags: jquery

I have a php script which is displaying a name from a POST coming within a div like this

```
  <div id="runType">     
    <?php
        $test = $_GET['data'];
        echo $test;
    ?> 
</div>
```

This echos out 5k on the screen.

I then get this into the jQuery script like so

```
runType = $("#runType").text();
```

This all work ok and I can console.log out the runType and I get 5k

I then have an index array where I want to put runType into so I get the specific data

If I type the following I get the data I need

```
time.push(data[1]["5k"]);
```

So I though I could replace the 5k with runType variable like shown below but it does not work

```
time.push(data[1][runType]);
```

If I specify `runType = "5k"` it also works, so its something to do with how I'm getting the data from the DOM

if this possible

Comment: use `runType = $("#runType").html();` instead

Comment: I originally did it with html but this was not working so tried text thinking it might add as a string. I think its something to be with making it a string possibly

Comment: Could be a sync issue. I.e., the order of the things loading on the page and the JS functions firing. Could be that your jQuery grab function is firing after your `time.push` function, or push function is firing before DOM is loaded..? Would need to see all of the relevant code to judge.

Comment: I getting the data from the DOW within document.ready and displaying this in the console.log before calling the function so this should not be a timing issue